# apple script handler not working in tell statement

Tags: applescript, automator

Hi I am writing a script that will rename selected files / folders in the format xxxyearxxx to be xxxyear. I am new to apple script, have done plenty of autoit / c++ stuff.

I can't get my handler to work in a tell statement. I have tried everything ("my", " of me") and get errors with the handler. The Handler works fine when called outside of the tell statement:

with "my", The script does not compile and I get the following error: Syntax Error: A command name can’t go after this “my”.

with "of me" This script does compile and run, but i get the following error: "Finder got an error: The using parameter is missing for splittext." number -1701 from «class by  »

Any help to get around would be very helpful.
Script below:

`

```
set MaxYear to 2018
set MinYear to 1990
-- return splittext {"abc2015def", 2018, 1990}


tell application "Finder"
set allfiles to every item of (choose folder with prompt "Choose the Files you'd like to rename:" with multiple selections allowed) as list
-- set allfile to selections

repeat with x in allfiles
    if kind of x is "Folder" then
        -- if xtype is "Folder" then
        set cname to name of x
        set newname to splittext {cname, MaxYear, MinYear} of me
        if newname then
            set name of x to newname
        end if
    end if
end repeat
end tell


on splittext {theText, MaxYear, MinYear}
set dyear to MaxYear
repeat until dyear < MinYear
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to dyear
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    if (count of theTextItems) > 1 then
        return the first item of theTextItems & dyear as string
    end if
    set dyear to dyear - 1
end repeat
return false
end splittext
```

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks in this case I eventually found the error splittext is some sort of Internal AppleScript item. I was not adding the curly brackets the program was automatically changing my standard brackets to curly brackets.

Once I changed the name to _splittext Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

this code works, but ...

your handler :

```
splittext {theText, MaxYear, MinYear}
```

should be :

```
splitText(theText, MaxYear, MinYear}
```

*Note the parenthesis instead of curly braces (and the camel casing too).*

You should always return a string in your handler :

```
return "" -- return false
```

And in the repeat loop above :

```
if newname is not "" then -- if newname then
```

There is another pitfalls : the kind of x. It is a local string i.e. "Folder" will be "Dossier" in French. You should maybe do something like this if you're not from English spoken country :

```
log kind of x
```

So the whole code that works on my machine (10.12.6) :

```
set MaxYear to 2018
set MinYear to 1990
--return splitText("abc2015def", 2018, 1990)

tell application "Finder"
    set allfiles to every item of (choose folder with prompt "Choose the Files you'd like to rename:" with multiple selections allowed) as list
    -- set allfile to selections

    repeat with x in allfiles
        log kind of x
        if kind of x is "Folder" then
            -- if xtype is "Folder" then
            set cname to name of x
            set newname to my splitText(cname, MaxYear, MinYear)
            if newname is not "" then
                set name of x to newname
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell


on splitText(theText, MaxYear, MinYear)
    set dyear to MaxYear
    repeat until dyear < MinYear
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to dyear
        set theTextItems to every text item of theText
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        if (count of theTextItems) > 1 then
            return the first item of theTextItems & dyear as string
        end if
        set dyear to dyear - 1
    end repeat
    return ""
end splitText
```